# React pattern Container (logic) / Component (view) question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a react app alone and therefore, I have few general questions that are left unanswered regarding code pattern.

I am following the Container (logic) / Component (view) split and I am often rendering a Container from a Component.

I don't see how it could be avoided as you sometimes need multiple levels of depth.

Can you confirm that it is a normal thing?

One case I'm concerned about is when a Component (view) renders a Container (logic), I sometimes need to pass the reducer to the Container (logic) as a prop -- associated object Action type (which describes the action type and payload type) -- which forces me to import the reducer.ts file in the Component (view) in order to pass it as a prop to the Container (logic), the reducer.ts was supposed to be used and is located in the Container's (logic) folder.

Note: my folders are structured like this.

src/

- containers/

  - A/(index.tsx,reducer.ts)
  - B/(...)
  - C/(...)
- components/

  - A/(index.tsx)
  - B/(...)
  - C/(...)

Consider a case where the top-level caller is A and it shares a state managed by a reducer with B.
The prop drilling goes as container A > component A > container B. The problem is that component A whll have to import

`components/A/index.tsx`

```js
import { B } from 'containers';
import { Dispatch } from 'react';
import { Action } from 'containers/A/reducer'

interface AProps {
   dispatch: Dispatch<Action>;
}

return <B dispatch={dispatch}/>;
```

Thanks!